# Why does selecting distinct before unioning returns more columns than doing it after?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Pyspark, and I have 4 data frames, each having the same schema. I want to count the distinct ids in them all.

But if I do:

```py
combined_df1 = (df1.select('id')) \
  .union(df2.select('id')) \
  .union(df3.select('id')) \
  .union(df4.select('id'))

combined_df1.select('id').distinct().count()
```

I get a higher figure than if I do:

```py
combined_df2 = df1 \
  .union(df2) \
  .union(df3) \
  .union(df4)

combined_df2.select('id').distinct().count()
```

About 10% more rows returned, not an insignificant amount. What's going on here?

Why does it matter whether I select distinct `id` before or after the union? It's the same list of `id`s either way isn't it?

Comment: please add [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you have a strange behavior like this one, the first thing is to identify where does the problem comes from. Write 1st query in a table, write the 2nd one elsewhere. Compare the content. Are they both distinct ? What are the additionnal IDs ? which dataframe do they belong to ? Try replace `union` with [`unionByName`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName)

Comment: Yes! unionByName fixed it - thanks!! If you put it in an answer I'll tick it off. So this means the columns have ended up in a different order somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is difficult to be sure, but my guess is that your columns/schemas in each dataframe do not have the same order. `union` merges your dataframe into one big dataframe where the ID column of the first dataframe is "unioned" with another column of the next dataframes. Therefores, the disctint "fails" because it tries to dedup inapropriated values.

The solution is to replace `union` with [`unionByName`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName).

---

To answer exactly your question :

> Why does it matter whether I select distinct id before or after the union?

TL;DR ==> Union does not distinct the values.

Let's take a simple example, with 2 dataframes :

df1:

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

df2:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 3 |

---

```
id1.distinct ==> [2,3]
id2.distinct ==> [1,3]

id1.distinct().union(id2.distinct) ==> ([2,3]).union([1,3]) ==> [2,3,1,3] (4 elements)
```

```
id1.union(id2) ==> [2,2,3,1,1,3]
id1.union(id2).distinct() ==> [1,2,3] (only 3 elements)
```

You see that doing the distinct afterwards removes the duplicates that exist between your dataframes.

Comment: But there's a distinct before doing the count.

Comment: `.select('id').distinct()` does though right? And I'm doing this after the union in both cases.

Comment: @user43107 sorry, just focused on your quesiton `Why does it matter whether I select distinct id before or after the union?`

Comment: @Steven, no probs, my fault it was a tricky one to phrase! Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: @user43107 See my comment on your post. My guess is that using `unionByName` should fix your problem. But without a reprex, it is difficult to be sure.